# Передача параметров в программу использующую MPI

Tags: c, mpi

Добрый день. Не могу понять как задать количество процессов. Если я запускаю программу первым способом:
`mpiexec -l -n 5 ./test` - то отработает 5 процессов.

Но мне необходимо запустить программу через передачу аргументов:
`./test 5` - и в этом случае отработает 1 процесс
Что для этого мне следует изменить? Если просто указывать параметр procs_count при инницализации - не работает.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
   int procs_rank, procs_count;
   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   // инициализация MPI-библиотеки
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procs_count);
   // определяем количество процессов
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procs_rank);
   // узнаем ранг процесса
   printf ("\n Hello, World from process %3d of %3d\n", procs_rank, procs_count);
   MPI_Finalize();
   // закрываем MPI-библиотеку
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для передачи параметров (аргументов командной строки) просто напишите их после всех остальных аргументов mpiexec. Например : `$ mpiexec -n 5 ./a.out 123`

В отличие от mpiexec, ./ создаст единственный процесс.